Solve the equation for the variable $x$. $\sqrt{x}+a\sqrt[3]{x}+b\sqrt[6]{x}+ab=0$

Solve the equation for the variable $x$. The constants $a$ and $b$ represent positive real numbers. $\sqrt{x}+a\sqrt[3]{x}+b\sqrt[6]{x}+ab=0$

$x^{\frac{1}{2}}+ax^{\frac{1}{3}}+bx^{\frac{1}{6}}+ab=0$
$x^{\frac{3}{6}}+ax^{\frac{2}{6}}+bx^{\frac{1}{6}}+ab=0$
$x^{\frac{2}{6}}(x^{\frac{1}{6}}+a)+b(x^{\frac{1}{6}}+a)=0$
$(x^{\frac{1}{3}}+b)(x^{\frac{1}{6}}+a)=0$
$x^{\frac{1}{6}}+a=0$
$\sqrt[6]{x}=-a$
Now the solution says "since $\sqrt[6]{x}$ equals the real number $-a$ and by definition is positive, this cannot yield a solution." I don't understand this. The sixth root can be positive or negative because it is even. $a$ is positive, but when I move it across the equal sign naturally it becomes negative. What is the issue here?

I think you have your even/odd reversed here... (can you think of a real number that satisfies $x^6=-1$?)

You seem to have lost half of your options proceeding from "$(x^{1/3} + b)(x^{1/6} + a) = 0$": when a product of things is zero, then at least one of them is zero.  You should obtain \begin{align*} x^{1/3} + b &= 0 &&\text{or}& x^{1/6} + a = 0 \end{align*} then study the two cases, check the solutions back in the original equation, then combine the valid solutions.

I was thinking if $x^2=7$, then $x=\pm\sqrt{7}$. Then it follows $\sqrt[6]{x}=\pm ...$ because $6$ is even. Negative/positive to an even power becomes positive.

Right, so if both negative and positive numbers, to an even power, give you a positive result, how can you end up with $-a$?

I see... so only in this case would it make sense? $-\sqrt[6]{x}=-a$

$$\sqrt{x}+a\sqrt[3]{x}+b\sqrt[6]{x}+ab=0\\(a+\sqrt[6]{x})(b+\sqrt[3]{x}
)=0$$
$a+\sqrt[6]{x}=0\implies\sqrt[6]{x}=-a<0$ since $a>0$. Therefore it is not a valid solution .
or
$b+\sqrt[x]{x}=0\implies x=-b^3 $
If we assume the principle root.
